# How to increase the height of a BottomSheetDialog to follow a vertical translation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm trying to move views vertically in a `BottoSheetDialog`, but I'm getting an unexpected behavior.

My `BottomSheet` looks like this

**Before Translation**

[image]

I'm moving my constraint Layout with
`myLayout.animate().translationY(-100f).setStartDelay(0).start()`

That's the `BottomSheet` after the translation:

**After Transition**

[image]

How can I increase the size of the `BottomSheet` dynamically to follow the translation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to solve this problem. I just added a empty view with 1dp height at the Bottom of my layout. I'm increasing it's size like this

```
val anim = ValueAnimator.ofInt(AnimationView.measuredHeight, 100)
anim.addUpdateListener()
{
     valueAnimator ->
     val value = valueAnimator.animatedValue as Int
     val layoutParams: ViewGroup.LayoutParams = AnimationView.layoutParams
     layoutParams.height = value
     AnimationView.layoutParams = layoutParams
 }
 anim.duration = 500
 anim.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can change the height of the `BottomSheet` programmatically, in my application, I'm using the following code to make the `BottomSheet` dialog take the height of the screen if possible:

```
BottomSheetBehavior mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from((View) sheetView.getParent());
mBehavior.setPeekHeight((int) (ScreenUtils.getScreenHeight()));
```

So in your case :

Change `(int) (ScreenUtils.getScreenHeight())` with your size value.

Comment: I doesn't work for me, maybe because my Layout has `wrap_content` as `android:layout_height`